# Incorrect value shown when calling parent function from child Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I try to call parent function from child component with dynamic value but the value is always showing 80 , Here is the code:

Parent:

```
filterdata = (child) =>{
        alert(child) // this is always showing 80
        this.setState({
            max:child
        })

    }
```

Inside `render()`:(`characters` is data fetched from axios)

```
<Pagination pages={Math.ceil(this.state.characters.length/10)} filter={this.filterdata} />
```

Inside Pagination.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Pagination extends Component {
    
    render() {
        
        var indents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.pages; i++) {
  indents.push( <li key={i} className="page-item"><a class="page-link"  onClick={() => this.props.filter((i+1)*10)}>{i+1}</a></li>);
}

        return (
            
            <div>

  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

{indents}
  
  </ul>

                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pagination
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't do the loop in the render, better do it in a function called when the component is mounted

Comment: @MarcCharpentier how to do this as I started learning react yesterday

Comment: But I get correct pagination from 1 to 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change your component to look like this for the sake of brevity. Like others said though, you could outsource the li generating logic to a method in your class later if the class becomes bigger. This isn't what's causing your problem, though.

I'm not sure what's causing the constant 80, but this code works for me.

in App.js

```
import Pagination from 'wherever it comes from';
import React from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = { max: null }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Pagination pages={5} filter={(val) => {
          console.log(val);
          this.setState({ max:val });
        }} />
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Pagination.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                    {Array(this.props.pages)
                        .fill()
                        .map((el, index) => {
                            const valueForFilter = (index + 1) * 10;
                            return (
                                <li key={index} className="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#" onClick={() => this.props.filter(valueForFilter)}>
                                        {index + 1}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man just one more question does this `Array(this.props.pages).fill()` create an array?

Comment: @aryanagarwal Yes. Array() accepts a number the defines the length of the array, then fill() accepts anything you want to fill it with, or you can leave it empty to fill it with null. You can't map over an array before using .fill() if you're using Array() to create it though.

Answer (score 2):

Like Marc said, I don't think you should do the loop inside render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Pagination extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { indents: [] };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        vat indents = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.pages; i++) {
            indents.push(<li key={i} className="page-item"><a class="page-link"  onClick={() => this.props.filter((i+1)*10)}>{i+1}</a></li>);
        }
        this.setState({ indents: indents });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                    {indents}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pagination
```

Also, you are using class instead of className on the ul element.

Comment: Your second example won't work. Pages is a number, not an array.

Comment: First is showing  unexpected token a constructor was expected

Comment: @DavidFrederick good point. I totally missed that. I'll remove it.

Comment: @aryanagarwal fixed it. It was a bad copy/paste job on my part. The code was supposed to be inside the render function and I accidentally put it before.

Comment: `Like Marc said, I don't think you should do the loop inside render` , but you still write loop inside render and your code is same as mine

Comment: @aryanagarwal I'm answering more than one question at a time and having a conversation and lost what I was doing. Yes, I've fixed it. Hopefully I didn't miss anything this time.

Comment: @DillanWilding Thanks for your effort man